Blender crashes when Partenting rig with my model
I created a character. Now I wanted to rig it. I made my rig, and then I wanted to parent my model to the rig with automatic weights. When I clicked it, it showed the loading symbol for a few minutes, and then Blender crashed. I tried it a few times, and the same thing happened each time. What should I do?

Hello, maybe your mesh is too dense? How many vertices does it have?

Yes, that was it. Thank you very much!!! It had way too many vertices. I reduced them and now it works!!!

Your mesh is too dense, lower down the amount of vertices
